# Android - ¿Cómo hago para que la imageView (Splash) se muestre fullscreen y sin márgenes?

Tags: java, android, xml

Tengo un Splash que se muestra antes de que se cargue un WebView y este se está mostrando con márgenes izquierdo y derecho respectivamente. Quiero que esta imagen aparezca fullscreen. Todo funciona perfecto, salvo por ese "pequeño" detalle de los márgenes en la ImageView (que uso como splash). El código del activity_main.xml es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chapatelo.www.chapatelo.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashLoading1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:src="@mipmap/splash"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Al no estar seguro de si el ImageView sea la única parte a modificar para ver el Splash en full screen, les muestro mi main_activity.java para saber si debo agregar alguna función para lograr dicho efecto:

main_activity.java:

```
package com.chapatelo.www.chapatelo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.chapatelo.com.ar/");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
            mWebView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{}
}
```

Así se ve:

[image: Imagen]

El webview está por detrás y el splash delante y se muestra con márgenes (transparentes)

Comment: porque no agregas una imagen de como se muestra, los margenes en el ImageView o WebView....

Comment: Ya está agregada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La imagen se muestra asi ya que tienes especificado

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

y por default la centra sin perder el aspecto. Si deseas que cubra toda la pantalla agrega la propiedad

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sos mi salvadora!! Muchisimas gracias Elena!